# Getting the name of the plugin on hook: before_plugin_install

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

Using `Ionic / Cordova / Android`.

I've configured the hook: `before_plugin_install` on the file: `config.xml` in the following way:

```
<platform name="android">
    ...
    <hook type="before_plugin_install" src="scripts/my_test_hook.js" />
    ...
</platform>
```

Then, the file: `scripts/my_test_hook.js` has the following content:

```
module.exports = function(ctx) {

    console.log('#########################################');
    console.log(ctx);

};
```

Then, on the console, I get:

```
Installing "cordova-plugin-console" for android

#########################################

Context {
  hook: 'before_plugin_install',
  opts:
   { cordova: { platforms: [Object], plugins: [Object], version: '6.4.0' },
     plugin: undefined,
     nohooks: undefined,
     projectRoot: 'D:\\wamp64\\www\\ionic2\\tester-cordova-plugins\\01' },
  cmdLine: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\cordova\\bin\\cordova platform add android',
  cordova:
   { binname: [Getter/Setter],
     on: [Function: on],
     off: [Function: off],
     removeListener: [Function: off],
     removeAllListeners: [Function: removeAllListeners],
     emit: [Function: emit],
     trigger: [Function: emit],
     raw: {},
     findProjectRoot: [Function],
     prepare: [Function],
     build: [Function],
     create: [Function],
     emulate: [Function],
     plugin: [Function],
     plugins: [Function],
     platform: [Function],
     platforms: [Function],
     compile: [Function],
     run: [Function],
     info: [Function],
     targets: [Function],
     requirements: [Function],
     projectMetadata: [Function],
     clean: [Function] },
  scriptLocation: 'D:\\wamp64\\www\\ionic2\\tester-cordova-plugins\\01\\scripts\\my_test_hook.js' }
```

My question is: how do I get from within the file: `scripts/my_test_hook.js` (to do a `console.log(...)`) the name of the plugin, in the case above: `cordova-plugin-console`?

Comment: Are you able to upgrade cordova? 7.0.1 seems to work for me.

Comment: @davidesp What is the exact issue you are facing? Are you not able to identify the plugin or not able to log?